# Local Storage, and how to delay div visibility

Tags: javascript

I am using localstorage to show a div only once, and although the code it works very well, I would like to know how I can delay the visibility of this div ( **#alert** ) for 1 - 2 seconds (the first time the visitor is shown), and then do a fade in, so that it does not appear suddenly.

**My code:**

```
const showMsg = localStorage.getItem('showMsg');

if(showMsg === 'false'){
  $('#alert').hide();
}

$('.closebtn').on('click', function(){
  $('#alert').fadeOut('slow');
  localStorage.setItem('showMsg', 'false');
});
```

You can run the demo here:

https://jsfiddle.net/0966x2dw/7/

**My problem has a solution?**

Thanks.

---

**EDIT:**

Ops, right. I used CSS Transitions on my #alert div, and now it's much better.
Thanks.

https://jsfiddle.net/0966x2dw/23/

---

Comment: Using `setTimeout(function(){ //your alert},3000)` would make it https://www.w3schools.com/Jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Comment: `setTimeout(function(){....},2000)`

Comment: Use CSS transitions.

Answer (score 1):

First add "display: none;" to your .alert. Then you can do something like:

```
if(showMsg === 'false'){
    $('.alert').hide();
} else {
    $('.alert').delay(1000).fadeIn();
}
```

This will cause your alert div to bump the content below it down. You may want to use slideDown() instead to make it less abrupt.

(Note that if your alert is critical to your users, you should adjust this to make sure it displays for the small % of people who have Javascript off.)